Widescreen monitor with KVM (Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows)
Need help with choosing a monitor with inbuilt KVM and ability to split the screen into UBuntu and PC. I was looking at Dell 34inch but their display manager software doesnt offer Ubuntu support. Has anyone achieved this ? Would love some guidance

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of opinion based questions.
